# benefits of allocating huge pages at boot

Tags: linux, memory, huge-pages

The kernel boots with `default_hugepagesz=1G` option, which defines size of the default page size. So when an application want large memory, the kernel will allocate it with 1G pages.

If the kernel boots with `hugepages=N`, i.e. allocate N huge pages at boot. So in this case, the kernel will automatically take a page from this pool, thus saving time on allocating memory?

When this pool runs out of available pages, how will the kernel allocate huge memory?

Comment: You have a valid question, but you have posted to the wrong StackExchange site. I’m voting to close this question because your question is not "Programming" related, it is more appropriate for the StackExchange sites [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1):

`hugepages` kernel options reserves contiguous ranges of page frames (RAM), so that the user can allocate that many huge pages without fail.

When there are no reserved contiguous huge pages the kernel tries to find more, which may fail when the physical memory becomes fragmented.